# Hide/Show ion fab button programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

can anyone help me to find a way to `hide/show` specific button from the list of `button` of `ion-fab`

[image]

Comment: could you provide some could how you used to implemnt the ion-icon?

Comment: it's about <ion-fab-list></ion-fab-list> wich contains a list of ion fab button

Comment: Provide more code for answer, you can use *ngIf by giving condition

Answer (score 0):

i would dynamically render the list of fabButtons so that you only add the buttons to the list that are needed for the example

This is not the complete solution but something to get you started

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tab1",
  templateUrl: "tab1.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["tab1.page.scss"]
})
export class Tab1Page {
  fButtons = [
    { iconName: "logo-vimeo", isActive : true },
    { iconName: "logo-instagram", isActive : false },
    { iconName: "logo-facebook", isActive : true }
  ];
  constructor() {}

  getActive() {
    return this.fButtons.filter((i:any) => {
      return i.isActive === true
    })
  }
}
```

the template

```
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="share"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-list side="top">
      <ion-fab-button *ngFor="let b of getActive()">
        <ion-icon name={{b.iconName}}></ion-icon>
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Ionic framework, then use this sample code

```
<IonFabList side="top">

  <IonFabButton *ngIf="..." color="primary">
    <IonIcon icon="logo-facebook" />
  </IonFabButton>

  <IonFabButton *ngIf="..." color="primary">
    <IonIcon icon="logo-twitter" />
  </IonFabButton>

  <IonFabButton *ngIf="..." color="primary">
    <IonIcon icon="logo-youtube" />
  </IonFabButton>

  <IonFabButton *ngIf="..." color="primary">
    <IonIcon icon="logo-vimeo" />
  </IonFabButton>

</IonFabList>
```

in `*ngIf` write your conditions

Comment: i already use this but it's not working for me, the problem created using *ngIf is the ionic frameword use a className "hide" and "show", so if i use *ngIf dosen't control the classname added by ionic to ion fab button.

Comment: you want to add or remove class name (`hide` and `show`) dynamic in to element? is it correct?

Comment: yeap, but the problem here is the ionic add automaticly hide and show, so if i use ngClassName i found "hide hide" or "hide show"

Comment: try to use `[hidden]="..."` on element